# Interpreting coefficient from a nonlinear variable?

Tags: nonlinearity

How do I interpret the coefficient from an equation that has a logged dependent variable and an inverted control variable?  My model is of the form:

$$\ln Y = \frac{\beta}{x} + \text{other terms} + \varepsilon.$$

The partial derivative with respect to the control variable $x$ is:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ln{Y} = - \frac{\beta}{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain-rule to simplify the partial derivative gives:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ln Y = \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} \frac{d}{dY} \ln Y = \frac{1}{Y} \cdot \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}.$$

Hence, rearranging your partial derivative equation gives an equation for your coefficient:

$$\beta = - \frac{x^2}{Y} \cdot \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}.$$

Looking at this equation, we see that the $\beta$ coefficient has a complex interpretation.  It is possible to state this interpretation in words, but it is not very illuminating.